# How to make js cut off and change jump links?

Tags: javascript, html

How to make js cut off and change jump links?
Not just changing the herf of `<a>`.
There is no way to stop the jump of js.
I want to make a php proxy like https://github.com/joshdick/miniProxy but it's not perfect.
When encountering a jump with js, it will not work.

Comment: I am not sure, if I understand your question. Do you want prevent your browser from jumping to another section of you page, if you click on your link?

Comment: @Apollo79
no......

Comment: Nice clarification :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preventDefault behaviour with JS. By default it will redirect to link but you can:

```
document.getElementById("yourlink").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
});
```

Also, you can access your link with:

```
document.getElementById("yourlink").href;
```

or **event.target.href** inside your listener

Your **a** tag will need to have id of yourlink to achieve that:

```
<a href="someurl" id="yourlink" />
```

Comment: What if the way it jumps is js?

Comment: in JS: window.location.href = '<your-link>';